# I am having trouble with user defined functions

Tags: java, performance

I am a beginner in programming and I had to write a program which accepts the coordinates of two points in 3D and find the distance between them and their midpoint using functions and objects, but for some reason the input that I am giving for the second object is also being initialized to my first object and I do not know where I am going wrong. I have wrote the program below

```
    import java.util.*; 
    class D3Point 
    {
    static double x,y,z;
    D3Point()
    {
        x=0.0;
        y=0.0;
        z=0.0;
    }
    static void acceptPoint()
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("ENTER THE X-COORDINATE OF THE POINT");
        x=sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("ENTER THE Y-COORDINATE OF THE POINT");
        y=sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("ENTER THE Z-COORDINATE OF THE POINT");
        z=sc.nextDouble();
    }
    static void displayPoint()
    {
        System.out.println("("+x+","+y+","+z+")");
    }
    static double distance(D3Point P1, D3Point P2)
    {
        double a,b,c;
        double s,d;
        a=P2.x-P1.x;
        b=P2.y-P1.y;
        c=P2.z-P1.z;
        s=Math.pow(a,2)+Math.pow(b,2)+Math.pow(c,2);
        d=Math.sqrt(s);
        return d;
    }
    static D3Point midpoint(D3Point P1, D3Point P2)
    {
        D3Point P3= new D3Point();
        P3.x=(P1.x+P2.x)/2;
        P3.y=(P1.y+P2.y)/2;
        P3.z=(P1.z+P2.z)/2;
        return P3;
    }
    public static void main()
    {
        double d;
        D3Point Point1= new D3Point();
        D3Point Point2= new D3Point();
        D3Point Point3= new D3Point();
        Point1.acceptPoint();
        Point2.acceptPoint();
        System.out.println("THE COORDINATES OF THE TWO POINTS ARE:");
        Point1.displayPoint();
        Point2.displayPoint();
        d=distance(Point1, Point2);
        System.out.println("THE DISTANCE BETWEEN THE TWO POINTS IS ="+d);
        Point3=midpoint(Point1, Point2);
        System.out.println(Point1.x);
        System.out.println("THE MIDPOINT OF THE TWO GIVEN POINT IS");
        Point3.displayPoint();
    } 
    }
```

The second input that I am giving for the object Point2 is also being initialized to the object Point1. I have posted a similar question but they were not much helpful as I did not explained the question properly. And I am not allowed to use String[] arghs or anything similiar as I have not been taught that yet.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
static double x,y,z
```

says that all instances share the same coordinates - that's the meaning of `static` here.  Remove `static`.

Some but not all of your methods have a similar problem. For example:

```
static void displayPoint()
{
    System.out.println("("+x+","+y+","+z+")");
}
```

This is apparently intended to apply to a specific instance of the class, but `static` will prevent that.  Remove  `static`.

This doesn't apply to the cases where the "points" are passed as explicit arguments, such as

```
static double distance(D3Point P1, D3Point P2)
```

That can remain `static`.  The guideline is, if you want to call a method like `somePoint.something(...)` so the operation applies to the object `somePoint`, then it must not be a static method.

---

I made the above-suggested changes, cleaned up the layout a little, and used lower-case initial letters for variable names (by far the most common convention).  I made a separate class Main for the main function and test case because the online IDE I used seemed to insist (it's a good idea to keep that separate from the code that **implements** the D3Point class). I tested it at online-java.com. It apparently now works

```
import java.util.*; 
class D3Point {
    double x,y,z;
        
    D3Point() {
        x=0.0;
        y=0.0;
        z=0.0;
    }
    
    void acceptPoint() {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("ENTER THE X-COORDINATE OF THE POINT");
        x=sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("ENTER THE Y-COORDINATE OF THE POINT");
        y=sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("ENTER THE Z-COORDINATE OF THE POINT");
        z=sc.nextDouble();
    }
    
    void displayPoint() {
        System.out.println("("+x+","+y+","+z+")");
    }
    
    static double distance(D3Point P1, D3Point P2){
        double a,b,c;
        double s,d;
        a=P2.x-P1.x;
        b=P2.y-P1.y;
        c=P2.z-P1.z;
        s=Math.pow(a,2)+Math.pow(b,2)+Math.pow(c,2);
        d=Math.sqrt(s);
        return d;
    }

    static D3Point midpoint(D3Point P1, D3Point P2) {
        D3Point P3= new D3Point();
        P3.x=(P1.x+P2.x)/2;
        P3.y=(P1.y+P2.y)/2;
        P3.z=(P1.z+P2.z)/2;
        return P3;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        double d;
        D3Point point1= new D3Point();
        D3Point point2= new D3Point();
        D3Point point3= new D3Point();
        point1.acceptPoint();
        point2.acceptPoint();
        System.out.println("THE COORDINATES OF THE TWO POINTS ARE:");
        point1.displayPoint();
        point2.displayPoint();
        d = D3Point.distance(point1, point2);
        System.out.println("THE DISTANCE BETWEEN THE TWO POINTS IS ="+d);
        point3 = D3Point.midpoint(point1, point2);
        System.out.println("THE MIDPOINT OF THE TWO GIVEN POINT IS");
        point3.displayPoint();
    } 
}
```

Comment: I tried removing static but it still did the same thing

Comment: Works for me. See updated answer.

Comment: it was a mistake on my part, i removed the static from the functions but i forgot to remove static from the variables, it is working now, so thank you for your help